# display data from sqlite according to value

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

i need your help, i did display data in a list view but the problem is that i

want the data to be according to a specific value, that means if the id = 1, only the rows

concerned will be displayed, if you have any suggestions i would be very thankful :

here the code of :

```
    public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

  private static final int FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER = 2;
  private Cursor cursor;
  SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = null;
  Cursor c;
   DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
   @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
   @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

try {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    db.open();
    populateListViewFromDB();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("ERROR", "Error occured: " + e.toString());
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  }
 @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
 private void populateListViewFromDB() {
 Cursor cursor = db.getAllRecords();
 startManagingCursor(cursor);

 String[] databaseColumnNames = new String[] { DBAdapter.col_region, };
int[] toViewIDs = new int[] { R.id.text };

  SimpleCursorAdapter myCursordapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.activity_main, cursor, databaseColumnNames, toViewIDs,FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);
         ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

And my DBAdapter is :

```
 private static final String MENAGE = "table_MENAGE";

   public static final String _id = "Num_du_Questionnaire";

 public Cursor getAllRecords() {
 return db.query(MENAGE, new String[] { _id, col_region,
         }, null, null, null,
          null, null);
  }
          list.setAdapter(myCursordapter);
     }  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you may check in [query](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) documentation, function accepts a `selection` and `selectionArgs` parameters, corresponding to SQL `WHERE` clause.

So, to make a query limited to a specific id, just use:

```
db.query(MENAGE, new String[] { _id, col_region}, "id = ?", new String[] {_id}, null, null, null);
```